# Prevent text from being inserted inside html in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I have a div with contenteditable, and inside of it is a link:

```
<div contenteditable>
  <a id="a">[$special.value$]</a>
</div>
```

If the user clicks into the field at the end and starts typing, the new text is inserted inside the `<a>` rather than after it.

```
<div contenteditable>
  <a id="a">[$special.value$] new text added here</a> instead of here
</div>
```

How can I make sure that new text gets added outside the `<a>`?

I've tried adding `contenteditable="false"` on the `<a>` but this adds a number of other quirks.

Right now, the best I can come up with is to use a `&zwnj;` before and after links - this prevents the text from being added inside the `<a>` but it makes the cursor movement a little odd (you have to move left/right an extra time)

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Normal
<div contenteditable>
  <a id="a">[$special.value$]</a>
</div>

With zwnj
<div contenteditable>
  <a id="a">[$special.value$]</a>&zwnj;
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you wrap the element inside `<a>` tag when it doesn't link anywhere ?

Comment: It could even be a `<span>` or some other html, the problem is that new text gets added inside it

Comment: I'm not noticing anything strange with the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Create another element (a `<span>` for example) inside the `<div>` and set its `contenteditable` to `true`. Then set the `<div>` to float to the left and the `<span>` to display as a block element.

```css
div.container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

a {
  float: left;
  color: red;
}

span[contenteditable] {
  display: block;
  width:   100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" id="a">[$special.value$]</a>
  <span contenteditable></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered temporarily removing the `a` element when the `contenteditable` gets the focus and then pre-pending it back in when it loses the focus?

```js
let old = "";
document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").addEventListener("focus", function(){
  old = this.innerHTML; // Store the current data
  this.innerHTML = "";  // clear out the element
});

document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]").addEventListener("blur", function(){
  // Set the new content to the old concatenated with the current
  this.innerHTML = old + this.textContent;
});
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

a { color: red; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable>
  <a id="a">[$special.value$]</a>
</div>
<p>...Hit [TAB] or click outside of element after typing...</p>
```